# Redoing css-layout jsfiddle in react v0.13

Tags: reactjs

I have been playing with this jsfiddle which shows how to use css within js: http://jsfiddle.net/vjeux/y11txxv9/

In the above jsfiddle, the following three functions seem to be deprecated for `React v0.13.1`.

```
var View = React.DOM.div;
var Text = React.DOM.span;
....
React.renderComponent(<div style={{width: '100vw', height: '100vh'}}><StyleDemo /></div>, document.body);
```

It seems that the code after refactoring should be something like below for `React 0.13.1`:

```
var View = React.createElement('div');
var Text = React.createElement('span');
...
React.render(React.createElement("div", {style: {width: '100vw', height: '100vh'}}, React.createElement(StyleDemo, null)), document.body);
```

However, above refactoring doesn't seem to work - nothing renders in Chrome after refactoring. Since my knowledge of JS and React is quite limited, I will appreciate pointers on how to refactor above code for `React 0.13.1`.

To test the above code on my computer, I created `index.html` and `test.js`, both of which are attached below.

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 100;
}
div, span {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    border: 0 solid black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

 </style>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.1/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.1/react.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script type="text/jsx" src="test.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

`test.js`:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var StyleSheet = { create: function(e) { return e; } };
var View = React.createElement('div');
var Text = React.createElement('span');



var StyleDemo = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.card}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <View style={styles.profilePicture} />
          <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Text style={styles.name}>Christopher Chedeau</Text>
            <Text style={styles.subtitle}>August 28 at 9:46pm &middot; Paris, France</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text>'react js' search on Twitter returns 96 results in the past 24 hours. I declare bankruptcy!</Text>
          <Text style={styles.bling}>Like &middot; Comment &middot; Share</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    margin: 15,
    padding: 8,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#cccccc',
    borderRadius: 3
  },
  profilePicture: {
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: '#cccccc',
    marginRight: 8,
    marginBottom: 8,
  },
  name: {
    color: '#3B5998',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 2,
  },
  subtitle: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: '#9197A3',
  },
  header: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },  
  bling: {
    marginTop: 8,
    color: '#6D84B4',
    fontSize: 13,
  },
});


React.render(React.createElement("div", {style: {width: '100vw', height: '100vh'}}, React.createElement(StyleDemo, null)), document.body);
```

Comment: Your new syntax isn't correct. You've changed it to only create one `div` instead of a `div` for each `View` usage. So, that will cause the render to not perform as expected.

Comment: @WiredPrairie, what would the new syntax should look like? If you want to, you could write it as an answer

Comment: @WiredPrairie, it seems React.createFactory (which is a function like React.DOM.div) instead of React.createElement will fix it. If this is what you have in mind, you should post it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `React.DOM` provides convenience wrappers around `React.createElement`
>   for DOM components ([Source](https://github.com/facebook/react/commit/eb2827ec6a6537c8ded127b0fb9dde271f94c7a8#diff-ef51787305cfed62f6f564284762d4de))

So you can use `React.createElement` but for regular html elements it's easier with JSX: just replace `<View />` with straight `<div />` (and Text with span)

Then you just need to rename `React.renderComponent()` (deprecated) with `React.render()` and it works.

New jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lt5skeab/1/
(External resources updated to use React 0.13.1)

Comment: that works. Curious though why `React.createFactory` wrappers for `div` and `span` don't work. I created another jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Lt5skeab/2/) off yours with those variables defined. Insight into why they won't work would be very useful in understanding react library better.

Comment: Apparently `React.createFactory` is here to support a now deprecated way to create elements, which was to call components as functions. (source: https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/ae327f2eda03bf165261) So unless you have a lot of legacy (pre 0.12 code) that works this way, I wouldn't spend too much time on `React.createFactory`.

Comment: aha, now makes sense. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction.